# Rotating a 3D Vector without a Matrix (OpenGL)

Tags: opengl, vector, matrix, rotation, degrees

I want to rotate a Vector(0, -10, 0) around the X and Y axis. I want to rotate X `rotX` degrees(0 - 360°) and Y `rotY` degrees(0 - 180°). I tried much but I couldnt get it done. Coudld anybody give me a solution for that? Some of my code I tried:

```
LightRotX = -posX;
LightRotY = -10 * cos((rotY) * PI / 180.0) - posZ * sin((rotY) * PI / 180.0);
LightRotZ = -10 * sin((rotY) * PI / 180.0) + posZ * cos((rotY) * PI / 180.0);

float bZ = LightRotZ;
float bX = LightRotX;

LightRotX = bZ * sin((rotX) * PI / 180.0) + bX * cos((rotX) * PI / 180.0);
LightRotZ = bZ * cos((rotX) * PI / 180.0) - bX * sin((rotX) * PI / 180.0);
```

Comment: Do tell us which version of OpenGL you're using and yes, if you've tried something (code) post it here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To rotate the point `(x,y,z)` around the `z` axis, the following works:

First, note that the `z` coordinate will stay the same.  So, the problem boils down to rotating the point `(x,y)` in the plane around the origin.  Let `theta` be the angle from the `x` axis defined as usual, and let `r` be the length of the vector `(x,y)` in the plane.  These can be computed as:

- `r = sqrt(x*x + y*y)`
- `theta = atan(y/x)`

Say you want to rotate by `phi` degrees around the `z` axis.  You want the point having length `r` but angle `theta + phi`.  Its coordinates are:

- `(r * cos(theta + phi), r * sin(theta + phi))`

Rotating around the `y` axis can be done similarly, by replacing every `y` in the above calculations with a `z`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to rotate a point(x,y,z) around the y axis, then here is what you need to do if you don't want to use Matrices. Think in terms of planes rather than axis. For the case of y, the plane of choice would be the x-z plane. Imagine a circle drawn on the x-z plane, when you rotate this point around the y-axis, it position can be defined as a point P(x,z) on the circle drawn on the x-z plane.

So in order to rotate around the y-axis, you need to change the x and z coordinates for your vector/point. To rotate 90 degrees:

```
NewX=cos(pi/2)*r
NewZ=sin(pi/2)*r
```

I can't gurantee the correctness of the above two lines of pseudo code, but if you get the idea, you'll be able to implement it.

If you change X and Y, you'll be rotating around the Z axis, which is the X-Y plane.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not really clear... Have you tried with the method glRotatef(angle, x_axis, y_axis, z_axis) where x_axis, y_axis, z_axis = {1.0, 0.0}; ?

Comment: I dont need OpenGL functions I think. I want to set the variables of my Vector, not using OpenGL to just change the render dimension

Comment: Maybe you have to do same trigonometrical calculations to represents the new vector from the old and an angle

Comment: Thats excactly what I want to do, but I need a solution for that. Mine wont work.